# Unable to open VS Code due to JavaScript error

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I attempt to open VS Code, I am seeing the following error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix5QJ.png)

Here is the transcript:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\main'
Require stack:
-
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:627:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-path.js:46:16)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\electron.asar\browser\init.js:191:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:850:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I am unable to open any projects in VS Code; any attempt throws the same error. I was running VS Code in the same session without any issues prior to receiving this error.

Comment: It happened after an extension update, probably the antivirus as suggested here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138893. I reinstalled it as recommended and everything seems fine now. Extensions and settings also seemed to have been kept.